# How to see how Android Firebase auth actually calls Firebase backend?

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

For example if I executed code like this:

```
Firebase.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .addOnCompleteListener { task -> signInCompletedTask(task) }
```

I would like to see what http request (and with what headers) is actually sent to Firebase backend.

What I tried:

- To find anything useful in logs, but I didn't see any information about this.
- To run application with debugger, but inside FirebaseAuth.class everything went so complicated that I still couldn't figure out where is the actual http request made.
- I tried to look for a source code for com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.java, I found this https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.java but this class seems wrong, it doesn't even have signInWithEmailAndPassword(..) method

In firebase doc I find this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-sign-in-email-password, but I'm not sure is this the same thing or not.

So bottom line, how can I debug what data is moving between my android application and Firebase backend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*firebaser here*

The source code you looked at is for the **Admin** SDK for Java backends, which doesn't have a way to sign in, but has lots of other useful calls for *administrative*/backend functionality.

For the Firebase Authentication Android SDK the code is in this repo `firebase-android-sdk`, but you'll find that the Authentication SDK is not in there (yet). If I recall correctly it was too entangled with Play to release it.

The Authentication SDK makes calls to the REST API though, and those endpoints are all documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth), like the API to [sign in with email+password](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-sign-in-email-password).

Comment: Thanks for verifying endpoints documentation location :). That would be cool if  Authentication SDK source would be public.

Comment: Agreed. I was actually surprised that it isn't yet, as most of our Android SDKs are.